# Is electrostatic induction saturated?

Tags: electromagnetism

If the electric field applied to the bulk of iron is made stronger and stronger, will the electrostatic induction be saturated by not having enough free electrons to produce enough polarization to cancel out of the electric fields?

Comment: I think you are leaving some context unsaid. If you are talking about a Faraday cage, say so because we cannot read minds.

Comment: I was imagining a steel block, but a Faraday cage would be fine.

Comment: I could have sworn this has been asked before but I cannot find. Unless there is a duplicate this is s perfectly good question and should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that may happen to a material (including a conductor) when it is exposed to an extra strong electric field: e.g., it may cause field emission of electrons from the material, Zener breakdown of electrons from the valence to the conduction band, etc.

However, it seems to me that the question has arisen as a consequence of studying electric induction as it is presented in high school or university E&M courses. These courses are dealing with the *electrodynamics of continuous media*, that is all the scales - time scales, spatial scales, strengths of fields, etc. are assumed to be such, that we can neglect the microscopic structure of the materials. In particular, the electrostatic induction is discussed under the assumption of an *ideal conductor*, i.e. material with infinitely many mobile electrons (for all practical purposes).

Theoretical concepts and limits of applicability of theories are just (or even more) important in physics as math.